# How to remove an audio function within an event listener?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a personal project based on selecting a random artist with a song attached to it. The thing is that I need to remove the "captionAudio(selected_image)" function so it can stop playing the song.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const random_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageList.length);
const selected_image = imageList[random_index];
modal.classList.add("open");
popImage.classList.add("open");
popImage.src = selected_image;
caption.textContent = captionText(selected_image);
playSound();
captionAudio(selected_image);
 });

modal.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if(e.target.classList.contains("modal")){
   modal.classList.remove("open");
   popImage.classList.remove("open");
   }
  });

function captionAudio (name){
 if (name == "images/blue-stones.jpeg"){
  playAudio8();
 } else if (name == "images/cage_d_elephant.webp"){
  playAudio1();
 }else if (name == "images/cold-war-kids.jpg"){
  playAudio2();
 }else if (name == "images/foster-the-people.webp"){
  playAudio3();
 }else if (name == "images/nujabes.jpeg"){
  playAudio4();
 }else if (name == "images/omam.webp"){
  playAudio5();
 }else if (name == "images/senor-loop.jpeg"){
  playAudio6();
 }else if (name == "images/tameimpala.jpeg"){
  playAudio7();
 }else {
  playAudio9();
 }
 }

function playAudio1(){
 const songs1 = new Audio();
 songs1.src = "./sounds/Cage-d-Elephant.mp3";
 songs1.play();
 }

function playAudio2(){
 const songs2 = new Audio();
 songs2.src = "./sounds/Colda-War-Kids.mp3";
 songs2.play();
 }
```

....

if you need the entire code I used for the whole page, let me know!

Comment: Where is the `captionAudio` function coming from? Is it a library or did you write it? If it's a library, which one is it? If you wrote it, you will probably need to include it in order to get helpful answers. Please do not include the code of the entire page, but do provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi! I added the captionAudio code. Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just pause it and forget about it? It should get garbage collected after it's paused. Also this is an extremely bad way to do this. Just have one function and pass a parameter instead of having 9 copies of basically the same function. Also store the audio file path in the element somewhere instead of having duplicate if statements. Side note, cases where these types of duplicate if statements are actually needed can be replaced by a case statement instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm new at this and I'm trying to get any knowledge I can. Here's the page if you wanna check it out : https://gabo005.github.io/Music-Random-Selection/